# Customizing ActionBar TabBar in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am using ActionBar (ActionBarSherlock (version 4.2) for pre HoneyComb devices) in my app, I have four tabs each of them having just an image on it.

Now my problem is I want 4th tab to be the smaller than the other ones, Other three must fill the space available and leave few pixels before the 4th tab starts.

Suppose for example, **first 3 tabs cover the 75% of screen width (25% each), then there is a space of 5% width (screen space) and the last tab takes just 20% of the screen width.**

How can I do that?

I have read a few threads here on Stack Overflow related to that but couldn't find any answer for my problem. A simple pointer towards the solution will be of great help.

Comment: It looks like you have to implement custom actionBarSharelock. Let me try and give you a example.

Comment: that will be so nice of you... I was also thinking on same direction but couldn't get pointers to start. Actually I have no idea from where to start ?

Comment: Even if I implement a custom ActionBarSherlock and provide this feature but how to make it available for post HoneyComb devices where original Actionbars are used...

Comment: OK. Let me some search or r&d on it.

Comment: why don't you try with this one ? Make 5 tab instead of four. Give them all the size as per you need. where first three tabs has the same size and fourth tab is nothing but just space. Fifth tab will be your original fourth tab. What you say ??

Comment: hummmmm . . . I think it can be possible. You just have to set the space for one device and then try to dynamically set it for all devices based on the height-width of the device. I think it is possible. Just try it and let me know.

Comment: now should i put the answer as explained above  ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try the following. Make 5 tab instead of four. Give them all the size as per your need. Where first three tabs has the same size and fourth tab is nothing but just space. Fifth tab will be your original fourth tab.